# Match values to rows before groupby column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a table that looks like the following:

```
+------+------+------+------+------------+
| ID 1 | ID 2 | Year | Type | Identified |
+------+------+------+------+------------+
|  100 |   50 | 2010 | CM   |         52 |
|  100 |   51 | 2020 | CN   |            |
|  100 |   52 | 2020 | S    |            |
|  100 |   53 | 2020 | A    |            |
|  200 |   60 | 2010 | CM   |         62 |
|  200 |   61 | 2020 | CN   |            |
|  200 |   62 | 2020 | S    |            |
|  200 |   63 | 2020 | A    |            |
+------+------+------+------+------------+
```

Only looking at `Type == "CM" | Type == "CN" | Type == "S"`, I would like to look at the number in the `Identified` column and match it to the corresponding row in `ID 2`. From rows with the corresponding value in `ID 1`, I am trying to look at the `Year` value. If there are multiple maximum dates, then I need to input a note into a new column that says something like "duplicate year".

The resulting table will look like this:

```
+------+------+------+------+------------+----------+
| ID 1 | ID 2 | Year | Type | Identified |   Note   |
+------+------+------+------+------------+----------+
|  100 |   50 | 2010 | CM   |         52 |          |
|  100 |   51 | 2020 | CN   |            | Multiple |
|  100 |   52 | 2020 | S    |            | Multiple |
|  100 |   53 | 2020 | A    |            |          |
|  200 |   60 | 2010 | CM   |         52 |          |
|  200 |   61 | 2020 | CN   |            | Multiple |
|  200 |   62 | 2020 | S    |            | Multiple |
|  200 |   63 | 2020 | A    |            |          |
+------+------+------+------+------------+----------+
```

I have started with the following:

```
q = df.query('(Type == "CM" or Fund_Type == "CN" or Fund_Type == "S") and Identified != ""')
my_query_index = q.index
```

Unfortunately, this only returns the index of rows where `Identified` is not blank. From knowing the indexes, I'm not sure how I can apply the indexes of needed rows to `df.groupby('ID 1')` and so on. All help and explanations appreciated.

EDIT: Will repost with better phrasing

Comment: "I would like to look at the number in the Identified column and match it to the corresponding row in ID 2". Where is this affecting your output? Even with just the second criteria you get the same thing

Comment: Can you be more specific about what your expected output is and why? It is quite confusing from your explanation. When you say, "If there are multiple"... multiple what?

Comment: I apologize, I forgot to add that it is marking the multiple maximum dates. I.e. if there are two rows within a group with maximum date 2020, mark both "multiple".

Answer (score 0):

Use masks and boolean indexing:

```
m1 = df.duplicated(['ID 1', 'Year'], keep=False)
m2 = df['Type'].isin(['CM', 'CN', 'S'])

df.loc[m1&m2, 'Note'] = 'Multiple'
```

Output:

```
   ID 1  ID 2  Year Type  Identified      Note
0   100    50  2010   CM        52.0       NaN
1   100    51  2020   CN         NaN  Multiple
2   100    52  2020    S         NaN  Multiple
3   100    53  2020    A         NaN       NaN
4   200    60  2010   CM        62.0       NaN
5   200    61  2020   CN         NaN  Multiple
6   200    62  2020    S         NaN  Multiple
7   200    63  2020    A         NaN       NaN
```

Setup:

```
data = {'ID 1': [100, 100, 100, 100, 200, 200, 200, 200],
 'ID 2': [50, 51, 52, 53, 60, 61, 62, 63],
 'Year': [2010, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2010, 2020, 2020, 2020],
 'Type': ['CM', 'CN', 'S', 'A', 'CM', 'CN', 'S', 'A'],
 'Identified': [52.0, nan, nan, nan, 62.0, nan, nan, nan]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: You're welcome. Take care, it seems 'Idenfied' column contains string but I'm not sure...

Comment: I didn't use "Identified" here, just followed the described logic

Comment: Yes but I think you have to take 52 and 62 from Identified column then get ID1 and Year from ID2